# Document.getElementById(...) is Null in Laravel View

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

**Message in console**

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null.

**Blade** (containing a button to delete)

```php
<td>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
            onclick="deleteSaleItem({{ $sale->id }})">
        i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
    </button>
    <form id="delete-form-{{ $sale->id }}" action="{{ route('secretary.sales.destroy.item',$sale->id) }}" method="POST"
          style="display:none;">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
    </form>
</td>
```

**Javascript implementation**

```
<script>

    function deleteSaleItem(id){
        const swalWithBootstrapButtons = swal.mixin({
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
        cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
        buttonsStyling: false,
        })

        swalWithBootstrapButtons({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
        reverseButtons: true
        }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById('delete-form-'+id).submit();
        } else if (
            // Read more about handling dismissals
            result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel
        ) {
            swalWithBootstrapButtons(
            'Cancelled',
            'Your data is safe :)',
            'error'
            )
        }
        })
    }
</script>
```

I need to know what is wrong with this code which results in null. Thank You.

Comment: Why don't you just put the button inside the form and listen to the form's "on subit" event?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one getElementById in your code.

```
document.getElementById('delete-form-'+id)
```

So, it might be the 'id' variable is empty or null and the element you retrieve become null.

Try debugging or console.log your 'id' variable just before document.getElementById code to see what happen to your variable.

Comment: When I log id via console it display the exact id number